# javascript で、同じ値のオブジェクトならば必ず同じ文字列になる stringify はどうやったら記述できる？

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Issue_with_plain_JSON.stringify_for_use_as_JavaScript

上記 javascript の、 `JSON.stringify` を見ていたのですが、そこで以下のような記述がありました。

> 配列以外のオブジェクトのプロパティでは、特定の順番で文字列化されることは保証されていません。文字列化された同じオブジェクトの中でプロパティの順番に依存しないようにしてください。

例えば、 stringify の結果を KVS のキーにしたいような場合、この性質はあまりいいものではありません。

#### 質問

- 同じ構造的な値を表す２つのオブジェクトが、同一の JSON 文字列に変換されるような stringify を実現するライブラリや手法などには、どのようなものがありますか？

Comment: json-stable-stringify は確認されましたか？ https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify

Comment: @ernix json-stable-stringify が、自分の欲しかったものの様子です (なので、回答していただけると、 accept ができるのですが。。)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json-stable-stringify` をお探しではありませんか？

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify

```
> var stringify = require('json-stable-stringify');
undefined
> var obj = { c: 8, b: [{z:6,y:5,x:4},7], a: 3 };
undefined
> stringify(obj);
'{"a":3,"b":[{"x":4,"y":5,"z":6},7],"c":8}'
```